Is there a safe way to add humidification to a central air system/heat pump?
It's currently very dry in my house due to the dry air outside, and I was going to buy a humidifier for my room.
I remembered that my air handler has a condensation tray which has a near continuous supply of a few cm of water, and was curious if that water could be somehow atomized into the outflow to humidify the air as it comes out of my vents. This would allow me to not worry about refilling the humidifier on particularly dry nights, and also not have a bulky large tank humidifier in my (fairly small) room.
Obviously, there's a reason the condensation tray is there in the first place (I'm guessing just a natural consequence of the heat pump's cycle), and there are two big reasons why you might not do this:

Rusting internal components
Mold buildup

I would think both of those could be solved if you didn't atomize too much water, but I'm not sure if it's possible to do that and also humidify the air sufficiently.
Is this feasible? If so, how would you do it?

That water comes from the air in the first place. If you are in the heating season you are not going to get water there.

Good point! I'm looking at whole house humidifiers right now

A central heat pump only condenses on one side.
In the summer, that is inside, like a traditional air conditioner. In the summer you want dehumidifying, so that's good.
In the winter, that is outside, because the cycle is reversed, so it is not dehumidifying the inside air. But the inside air is dry because (a) winter air is dry to start with and (b) as the air heats up, the relative humidity goes down, so it feels even drier.
The solution is a humidifier, preferably:

Plumbed to your water system, so you don't have to refill anything
Adding humidity inside the main ductwork, so the humidified air is spread throughout the house

There are a number of different ways to do that, but they are basically "spray a mist of water into the hot air". There are issues that make it a bit more complicated than that, including:

Mineral deposits clogging the equipment over time
Concerns about standing water
More pipes, valves, etc. = more chance for leaks

Look for "whole house humidifier" or "central humidifier" or similar and you will find options. But watch out for things that are self-contained boxes that do not connect into your ductwork. Those may produce enough humidity for a large house but unless the humid air is forced through the house somehow, the results will be very inconsistent - a jungle in one room and a desert in another.

The add-on whole humidifiers I've seen attach to the return air duct, near the furnace.  They are either the spray mist tyoe ( as was mentioned here) or a rotating wet sponge arrangement.  Both require connections to a water supply.
